# Cannot boot with 18.04 from USB stick on Acer Aspire 3 laptop with Windows

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, acer

I followed [the tutorial on how to create a bootable USB drive for a Windows machine](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) to the letter.

What happens when I try to boot from USB drive is I get to a menu where I select **Try Ubuntu without installing**. Then I get a blank screen. I waited 15 minutes and finally just powered the computer off by pressing and holding the power button for a few seconds.

I never got as far as the  purple splash screen with "Ubuntu" and 5 dots. Additionally, the tutorial does show FAT32 as the format, but in the latest version of Rufus that I used, the only choice was Large FAT32.

Please help me figure out what is wrong. Do I need to change some setting in Windows, or is there something else to be done with the thumb drive?

The laptop is an Acer Aspire 3 running Windows 10 with AMD Ryzen 5 2500U & AMB Radeon Vega Mobile Graphics, with 8 GB DDR4 memory.

EDIT:  There's a new problem. I shut down, inserted the USB drive, and powered on. The Windows computer simply ignores the drive and boots right to Windows 10.

Comment: @karel I modified my original question somewhat. My problem isn't quite the same, as I never got as far as the "5 dots".

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question doesn't say anything about a purple screen with 5 dots as you can see by looking at the screenshots, so forget about the 5 dots screen for now. You're at the purple **ubuntu** menu where one of the options is *Try Ubuntu without installing*, OK? Don't select that option. Press the F6 key instead and select the  `nomodeset` option first. Afterwards continue and select the *Try Ubuntu without installing* option as before.

Comment: @karel, see edit to original post. Now I can't even get to GRUB, goes right to Windows.

Comment: I know you don't want to hear this, but the second part of that same answer also works to get to the GRUB screen, even if it boots right into Windows.

Comment: Seems like a classic mis-made LiveUSB. Download the iso file again, check the hashes to ensure it wasn't corrupted in transfer, use a good USB stick, and don't hurry rufus. It really does work.

Comment: @karel Pressing F6 at the GRUB menu does absolutely nothing. There is no response when pressing F6.

Comment: @karel I don't understand your second comment about pressing F6. Once I am in Windows, F6 doesn't do anything, either.

Comment: You haven't read the answer yet or if you have read it you haven't done what it says to do in that answer. You don't have to read the accepted answer if you don't want to read it. Try everything else instead.

Comment: This is not helpful. I have made the  USB boot stick following the directions to the letter. The only exception is that in the illustration it was "FAT32" but the only choice Rufus gave me was "Large FAT32". When I do get to grub, I tried what @karel suggested and pressed F6. It did nothing.

Comment: That's not what I said. Read the answer and you'll understand that that's not what I said. F6 was only for the **ubuntu** screen. You're not stuck at that screen anymore. I know you don't want to reads that answer, so don't read it. Try everything else instead, but please stop insisting that you tried that answer because you still haven't done what that answer says to do. Do whatever you want, I don't care but stop insisting that you tried the answer because you still haven't done what that answer says and probably never will.

Comment: What is with the nastiness? Won't ever come here for help again.

Comment: Try **UNetbootin** for Windows, I have had much more success with it than with Rufus.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @karel for the comment under the question.

In Grub menu I pressed e to edit the bootentries and could boot my system to the installer now with the nomodset option.

So, if you still need to try something:
On grub menu:
- select the entry you wish to use
- press to edit the entry before booting
- add 'nomodeset' to the entry and press F10